# Navigate to root route "/"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to navigate to home route from a child route but nothing happens.

I.e. the current route is `/projects`

Neither `this.router.navigate(['/'])` nor `routerLink="/"` works.

My `routerConfig` looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: HomeComponent
 },
 {
   path: '/projects',
   component: ProjectsComponent
 }
]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: try to add parent... Like this: this.router.parent.navigate(['/'])

Comment: Also when you say child route it would be helpful if you added your directory hierarchy so I could see exactly what you are trying to do. I am pretty sure my answer will help you but if it does not then show me how your directories are setup so I can help more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding a `redirectTo` route to your routes config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent }
];
```

Comment: This works right. Though I don't understand why my method couldn't work. Could you elaborate why creating a redirect route works.

Comment: It has to do with the child components. For example I think if your home component. Was actually next to app.component and not in /components/home.component I do not think this would be necessary. I am honestly not exactly sure but I have spent 6 hours on this myself. So I feel your pain brother I feel your pain.